# Items that span all columns/rows using CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

With the CSS Grid Layout Module soon shipping in Firefox and Chrome, I thought that I'd try to get a handle of how to use it.

I've tried to create a simple grid with one item `a` spanning the left side of all of the rows, with the other items (`b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, etc.) spanning the right side of individual rows. The amount of items spanning the right side of the rows is variable, so there might be any combination of `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, etc., so I'm using the `grid-auto-rows` property. As such, I cannot define a fixed number of rows for `a` to span, but I would like `a` to span *all* available rows.

```css
#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: [left] 4rem [right] 1fr;
    margin: 0rem auto;
    max-width: 32rem;
}
#a {
    background: lightgreen;
    grid-column: left;
    grid-row: 1 / auto;
    justify-self: center;
}
#b {
    grid-area: auto / right;
    background: yellow;
}
#c {
    grid-area: auto / right;
    background: pink;
}
#d {
    grid-area: auto / right;
    background: lightskyblue;
}
#e {
    background: plum;
    grid-area: auto / right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
    <div id="d">d</div>
    <div id="e">e</div>
</div>
```

What should I do to make `a` span all rows without knowing how many rows there will end up being?

Comment: I'm digging into CSS Grid also and I'm having the exact same problem.  I feel like there's something easy I'm missing.

Comment: I'll write this up as a full answer when I have a sec, but the key is a grid inside of a grid. So make another div next to 'a' that holds b, c, d, e and all the rest - let's call it 'content_holder'. Then add display: grid; to 'content_holder'. It will auto size to the content and 'a' will auto-size to it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Supossedly grid-row: 1 / -1 should do it, but it doesn't work with auto rows apparently :(

Answer (score 234):

I had the same situation and found a clean solution.

Instead of using a huge row span value, try:

```
grid-column: 1/-1;
```

As negative number counts from the right, this code specifies the `grid-column` to the end of the last column.

Note: In case this doesn't apply, check Jonny Green's solution in the below comment.

Comment: Beautiful solution, worked for me in the case that I had 1 cell which I wanted to span the full width and a bunch of other cells which I wanted to be 1 cell width. Defining `grid-column: 1 / span X` was breaking the responsiveness for me and this fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the number of columns is dynamic and unknown. Where the number of columns is not known, the solution I've found is `position: absolute;` and `width: 100%;` on the element to span all columns, and add `position: relative;` to the parent.

Comment: After a few days fighting with css, Jonny Green comment is what finally got it working (with the addition of `height: 100%;` on the element to span).

Comment: Just tried using Jonny Green idea on a layout, but realized it didn't work for me — SOMETIMES the content in #a might be taller than all the other content. In that case, position:absolute is not helping...

Comment: Though it's a hack, I was able to get away with `grid-row: 1 / span 99; height: 100%;`, knowing I'd never have anything even close to 99 rows (do 999 if you need to). I needed the element to still occupy space, which is why @JonnyGreen's solution didn't work for my needs.

Comment: This solution will only work in situations where there is an "explicit grid". [It will not work with implicit grids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076465/923560).

Answer (score 13):

**edit:** ***do not mind this answer unless you are about an obsolete browser*** ;)

---

You might use a hudge value of row to span *(at least as much you believe maximum of rows could be)* :

> *`grid-row: 1 / -1;` 12/19 , still not working in FF.*

**Edit** `grid-row: 1 / -1;` is now avalaible in latest Firefox too. **spanning a hudge value is not necessary anymore to mind Firefox behavior.**

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: [left] 4rem [right] 1fr;
  margin: 0rem auto;
  max-width: 32rem;
}
#a {
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-column: left;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 1000;/* hudge value ... will at least span so many rows */
  justify-self: center;/* ? what did you mean here ? */
  /* did you mean : */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
#b {
  grid-area: auto / right;
  background: yellow;
}
#c {
  grid-area: auto / right;
  background: pink;
}
#d {
  grid-area: auto / right;
  background: lightskyblue;
}
#e {
  background: plum;
  grid-area: auto / right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
  <div id="d">d</div>
  <div id="e">e</div>
</div>
```

or did you mean:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: [left] 4rem [right] 1fr;
  margin: 0rem auto;
  max-width: 32rem;
}
#a {
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-column: left;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 1000;/* hudge value ... will at least span so many rows */
  align-self: center;
  justify-self:center
  }
#b {
  grid-area: auto / right;
  background: yellow;
}
#c {
  grid-area: auto / right;
  background: pink;
}
#d {
  grid-area: auto / right;
  background: lightskyblue;
}
#e {
  background: plum;
  grid-area: auto / right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
  <div id="d">d</div>
  <div id="e">e</div>
</div>
```

Here is [a codepen to play with live](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xgBVKB).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this only works properly if `grid-row-gap` is not specified. If `grid-row-gap` is specified, the renderer will insert as many gaps as there are hudge rows....

Comment: (`justify-self: center;` is used only because I used vertically oriented text in my tests which I wanted centered in the column. I should have removed it from the example that I posted. Sorry!)

Comment: @Marlius for the `grid-row-gap`, you can turn it into margin . I forked my previous pen to add the margin (gap) and writing-mode .http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ygwbyv  (there was already a gap example on the third example in the first codepen http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xgBVKB :) . also to work row height should not specified else than auto. another example using javascript to set the span value needed : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BpZZQW (related to another similar question)

Comment: @Marlius the jquery pen revisited with the gap value http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pRYPwK

Comment: Interestingly, this approach works if you use a large *negative* index: `row-grid: 1 / -1000`. A positive span index fails, however, due to it being based off the *explicit grid lines*, e.g. the rows you declare, of which you have none. [CSS Grid Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-int)

Comment: @AManOfScience Can you tell me where it fails. Actually grid is still experimental and spec still in evolution (`grid-row : span all;` as for column would be useful), For tthe browsers where i tested this , it worked (FF & webkit) The other (& solid) approach is to use javascript to count elements to set the rows to span. as commented earlier  and linked to an example ;)

Comment: By *fail* I was referring to your above conversation about `grid-row-gap`. I'm going off the W3 document I linked; "If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in reverse, starting from the end edge of the explicit grid." Using a negative index provides a pure-CSS solution, for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: @AManOfScience okay, good point id did not pay attention to !!

Comment: Your update states that `grid-row: 1 / -1` now works in Firefox, but that does not seem to be the case. If you change `grid-row-end: span 1000` to `grid-row-end: -1` it will only be in the first row.

Comment: @fritzmg it does work but you need to set a numbers of row, value of spanning has to be turned to `grid-template-rows:repeat(100,auto);`  So same issue if you set vertical gaps ;)  forked of the demo pen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWoKqoW

Comment: It does work yes, but not when the amount of rows is not fixed.

Comment: @fritzmg yes indeed, FF, chrome ... they all have the same behavior .  both ways are now working in latest browser. I do not think that it will be possible without it in the future :(

Answer (score 0):

As of today this is a feature still up for consideration as per this https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2402