# Using negative integers with implicit rows in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to make a simple sidebar layout with a flat HTML structure, in which the first `<aside>` element fills in the 1st column completely.

My problem is, that the negative row end value seems to not work for the implicitly created rows for all my elements in the 2nd column.

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

Below is a runnable code snippet that illustrates the problem.

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  background: gray;
}

aside {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background: pink;
}

section {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <aside>In the left column (top to bottom)</aside>
  <section>In the right column</section>
  <section>In the right column</section>
  <section>In the right column</section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can only use negative integers in an explicit grid.

See the Grid spec here:

> [**7.1. The Explicit
>   Grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)
>
> Numeric indexes in the grid-placement properties count from the edges
>   of the explicit grid. Positive indexes count from the start side
>   (starting from 1 for the start-most explicit line), while negative
>   indexes count from the end side (starting from -1 for the end-most
>   explicit line).

and here...

> [**8.3. Line-based Placement: the `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`,  `grid-row-end`, and `grid-column-end` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)
>
> If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in reverse, starting
>   from the end edge of the explicit grid.

Making a grid area span an entire column / row, including implicit tracks, when the number of tracks in the grid is unknown, is not possible in [CSS Grid Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), unless you want to try to [hack it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052563/3597276).

Comment: Thanks so much for giving a relevant source information. The hack is interesting, but I don't want to rely my solution on a hack.

I will go with wrapping all of my `<sections>` in a `<div>`. This way I will have only one row in the grid.

Comment: Good old `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;` might be a solution to this too on the item you want to fill. Make sure to remove `grid-area` first and add `position: relative` to the grid itself.