# CSS grid min span 3 and if class object is only object in grid row fill all grid elements in row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to design my web application. I want define that a class must have a min `grid-column` span of 3 frames and should span over the whole grid row, if the respective class object is the only one in the respective (in this case last row).

**Grid Definition**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, auto));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
  grid-gap: 50px;

}
```

**Respective Definitions**

```
.overalldata {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.clustergraph {
  grid-column: auto / span 6;
  justify-items: center;
}

.userinfoboard {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
  justify-items: center;
  align-self: center;;
}
```

My Browser on full width is allowing 19 columns. If I downsize the window, so that only 11 columns are allowed, the `userinfoboard` class object should span over the full width of the window, as it is the only object in its grid row.

How can I accomplish that?

I tried an answer for a [question that seems close to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239778/items-that-span-all-columns-rows-using-css-grid-layout), but it is missing the characteristic of `PSEUDO: min-span: span 3`:

```
.userinfoboard {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  justify-items: center;
  align-self: center;;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: don't think there is a "PSEUDO: min-span: span 3" in CSS grid... maybe a flexbox solution with relatively specified `flex-basis` will suit your question...

Comment: @kukkuz What would be the code to realize this?

Comment: can you share your html too?

Comment: I dont think you can. There is no CSS method of selecting an element by unknown last row let aone whether it's the only element in this row.

Comment: It must not be in the last row. But if the respective object is the only one in its grid row, then it should span over all grid elements. @Paulie_D

Comment: Regardless, CSS can't detect rows and so it has no method of determining whether the item is the only one on it.

Comment: Maybe something like: "Fill rest of empty grid elements"?

Comment: Nope...there is **no such thing as a "grid element".**

Comment: okay let me call it grid column

Comment: a flexbox possibility manipulating `flex-basis` and `max-width` (also taking into account the gutter between the items): https://jsfiddle.net/hsu0v23y/ fiddle with it and let me know if it suits your problem - will convert this to answer if it does

Comment: @kukkuz It perfectly fits! However, why is only the last div spanned over the whole width? I need every element that is the only one in its "row" to be spaced over the whole width, like the last row. :)

Comment: I thought only `userinfoboard` should have that behavior, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/2a9y7vrk/ (just removed the `max-width`s)

Comment: @kukkuz Sorry my bad! Your previous solution totally fits my idea! You are right. Only userinfoboard should have that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flexbox by manipulating `flex-basis` and `max-width` (also taking into account the gutter between the items):

- to create a *grid gap* you can apply a margin to the *flex items* and apply *negative margin* on the container,
- add `flex-grow: 1` to all *flex items* and set `calc(n * var(--column) + 2 * var(--gutter))` to span n columns,
- restrict `overalldata` and `clusterdata` from *growing* by specifying a `max-width` value same as `flex-basis`.

You can see that `userinfoboard` will now *span a minimum of three columns* - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  --column: 100px; /* size of one column */
  --gutter: 20px; /* size of gap between columns */
  margin: -10px; /* remove space between container and items */
}

.grid > * {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* grow items */
}

.overalldata { /* span three columns */
  flex-basis: calc(3 * var(--column) + 2 * var(--gutter));
  max-width: calc(3 * var(--column) + 2 * var(--gutter));
}

.clustergraph { /* span six columns */
  flex-basis: calc(6 * var(--column) + 5 * var(--gutter));
  max-width: calc(6 * var(--column) + 5 * var(--gutter));
}

.userinfoboard { /* span miniumum three columns */
  background: beige;
  flex-basis: calc(3 * var(--column));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="overalldata"></div>
    <div class="userinfoboard"></div>
    <div class="clustergraph"></div>
    <div class="overalldata"></div>
    <div class="userinfoboard"></div>
    <div class="clustergraph"></div>
    <div class="userinfoboard"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```